# Is rule 30 Turing complete? Is there a proof that it isn't?

Tags: computability-theory, cellular-automata

It is well known that the [elementary cellular automaton](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ElementaryCellularAutomaton.html) known as [rule 110](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110) is Turing complete.

Its cousin [rule 30](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Rule30.html) also produces complicated behaviour. When I read Wolfram's *a New Kind of Science* (in which these rules are defined), I vaguely recall his opinion being that rule 30 probably isn't Turing complete, because its behaviour is "too chaotic" - you tend not to get the localised regions of order that can be found in the dynamics of Rule 110, which probably makes it impossible for it to simulate a Turing machine in the same way.

If I recall correctly, there was no proof of this in the book. But that was many years ago. I would like to know if this intuition has been proven or disproven yet: has rule 30 been shown to be Turing complete, or is there now a proof that it cannot be?

If there is such a proof (or even if there isn't), I'd be interested to know what form it takes. In the case where something is Turing complete, one usually proves it by simulation: you use the system to implement a universal Turing machine, or some other thing that's known to be Turing complete. In the cases where something is too simple to be Turing complete, there are a number of ways to show this. (For example, you could show that every relevant question about its dynamics can be answered by a Turing machine that always halts.) However, in the case where something fails to be Turing complete because it's "too chaotic" in this way, I have no good intuition about how this could be shown.

Comment: The "Turing completeness" of rule 110 is a complicated issue (and too long for this comment). The Wikipedia article may be a little too eager to accept the claims of "Turing completeness" at face value.

Comment: If there's a notable objection, you could point me towards a paper, and/or edit the Wikipedia page if you felt so inclined.

Comment: In any case, one can still ask "is rule 30 in the same computational class as rule 110," i.e. does it satisfy the property that rule 110 has been proven to have, playing by the same rules of allowing a repeating initial condition but nothing more complex than that? This is a well defined question regardless of whether you think that property deserves the name "Turing complete".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such proof in either direction.

A proof of computational universality, like you said, would be to show that rule 30 can simulate computation (Turing machine or equivalent), and it would require extreme patience in experimenting with the cellular automaton as well as some creativity.

Proving the opposite would be more problematic, because there is no clear (generally accepted) definition what we consider as a computationally universal cellular automaton.  The problem is a cellular automaton configuration can carry an infinite amount of information.  If you allow too sophisticated encoding/decoding procedure for input/output of the computation, one might be able to perform all or a significant part of the computation by encoding/decoding and not the cellular automaton itself.  If you restrict the form of encoding/decoding too much, you would risk losing some interesting examples.  (For example, computation with rule 110 requires preparing a non-uniform periodic (infinite) configuration as the background of your input.)

Some references:

The difficulty is discussed in

- K. Sutner, [Universality and Cellular Automata](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sutner/papers.html), MCU'2004,

and mentioned briefly in

- N. Ollinger, [Universalities in Cellular Automata: a (short) survey](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00271840), JAC'2008.

General notions of computational universality in cellular automata and symbolic dynamical systems are discussed in

- J.-C. Delvenne, P. Kůrka, V. Blondel, [Decidability and Universality in Symbolic Dynamical Systems](http://iospress.metapress.com/content/eyxvfa8pum7qhbe4/), Fundamenta Informaticae, 74, 2006, and
- P. Di Lena, L. Margara, [Computational complexity of dynamical systems: The case of cellular automata](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ic.2008.03.012), Information and Computation, 206(9-10), 2008.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding your last paragraph, the same worry had occurred to me as well, while thinking about this stuff recently. I think it can probably be solved with some care about definitions, though. If you stipulate that the encoding has to be primitive recursive, for example (in some sense whose details have to be worked out) then at least it guarantees that some non-trivial component of some computations has to be done by the system itself and not by the encoding. Is the lack of an accepted definition something that people have commented on in the literature?

Comment: The initial configuration of the cellular automaton is an infinite object.  The encoding should therefore transform a finite string into an infinite string.  A primitive recursive function alone will not do, unless you add a non-trivial interpretation its output.  But then that interpretation is also part of your encoding.

Comment: Some years ago, there was a discussion about this.  For example, Matthew Cook gave a non-conclusive talk about this in AUTOMATA 2006.  There were also a couple of nice articles, but I have to check my large stacks of papers before giving you the references ... :-)

Comment: I meant something along the lines of, the initial state of each cell $i$ has to depend upon the input program $P$ according to a primitive recursive function $f(i,P)$. I'm not sure if that exact idea works or not (partly because it's much less clear how you do the decoding), but my intuition was that something like it should do the job. I look forward to those references if you get a chance to dig them out!

Comment: But still, one could just stipulate that the initial state has to be periodic (apart from a finite number of cells, which depend on the input program), and ask whether rule 30 is computationally reversible given that constraint (i.e. if it's universal in the same sense as rule 110). I'm still curious to know whether there would be a way to prove that this *isn't* the case. (If indeed it isn't.)

Comment: But why stopping at periodic background for the input?  What about having a non-periodic but simple initial configuration serving as the background?  Say, the background has $1$ at positions $\pm 2^n$ and $0$ everywhere else, and you put the input around the origin.

Comment: Only because those are the conditions under which rule 110 is universal, so it would be comparing like for like. I agree that a more general definition would be more satisfying. Many thanks for the references, that's really helpful. (I will probably accept your answer eventually, but I want to give others a chance to chime in.)

Comment: There is however an approach circumventing a proper definition: showing that all the logical statements about the dynamics of the cellular automaton expressible in terms of such and such properties are decidable.

Comment: I wonder if that's true for rule 30 though. If rule 30 is "too chaotic" to be Turing complete, then it might be that there are undecidable questions about it even if it's not universal. (I have heard that undecidable but non-universal things can indeed exist.)

Comment: Primitive recursive initial conditions are a bad idea, even if only used for fancy codings of eventually periodic initial conditions: Given a Turing machine, we can compute a primitive recursive description of the following configuration in polynomial time: put $1$ at $-n$ if the given Turing machine halts after exactly $n$ steps, and everything else is $0$. Rule 30 is left-permutive so if the machine halts, you eventually see $1$ at the origin and the configuration never becomes become periodic. If the machine doesn't halt, the configuration forever stays all-$0$.